# Make dashboard with Athena output of SQL Query from Editor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to use the output of sql query in Athena and turn that output into a dashboard/visuals so that it reflects the output in real time. I am researching this but I couldn't find the step by step approach to do this except few cloud watch links. Can anyone tell if it is possible to use the result of Athena query and produce the dashboard on a real time basis? Your suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena can act as a **data source**, just like a traditional database.

See: [Connecting to Amazon Athena with ODBC and JDBC drivers - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-bi-tools-jdbc-odbc.html)

You can then use a reporting/visualisation tool (eg **Amazon QuickSight**) to make a Dashboard with charts. Athena itself does not have any dashboarding/visualisation capabilities.

There are also open-source visualisation tools available. An example is [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/), which provides a 'notebook' interface and the ability to graph results.